# NSAppTransportSecurity not working in URL with port number

Tags: ios, ssl, nsapptransportsecurity

I have a problem here. I have to call two URLS:

**https://www.example.com/**

**https://www.example.com:83/**

In the first URL (without the port number), I have no problems because the SSL certificate is valid. But in the second URL (with the port number) the SSL certificate is invalid, so I'm going throw *kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue*.

I add NSAppTransportSecurity key in my Info.plist:

```
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    <key>example.com:83</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
</dict>
```

Unfortunatelly, this is not working. I'm thinking that maybe the error is related to the fact that I'm using a port number in the URL.

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: You only need a single entry in your info plist for `example.com`. The port number is not part of the domain, it is part of the URL.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not working